# The meaning of "How low can you go?"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In rap, I heard "How low can you go?" some times.
What does it mean? Is this phrase some fixed form? and is this used in everyday conversation as well?

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "How low can you go" is not usually encountered in conversation; it's an allusion, a line in Chubby Checker's 1962 recording *Limbo Rock*. It refers to a challenge dance called the limbo which requires the dancers to pass under a progressively lower bar on their feet while leaning backward, so "How low can you go?" is the literal challenge.

[image]

In Ludacris' 2009 recording *How Low* that surface meaning of the phrase shows up at a couple of points in the video, where one or more of the girls are actually performing limbo moves; but in the context of the song it's wrapped in several layers of double-entendre, such as *low* meaning 'vulgar', *get down (and dirty)* meaning 'participate enthusiastically in pleasurable or erotic activity', *go down (on)* meaning 'perform oral sex (on)', and doubtless more that I've missed.

But this was hardly new. The phrase is also employed to carry the prom scene in the 1971 musical/1978 film *Grease* to its orgiastic choreographic climax—see [this YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQnK1DNKnhg) at about 2:30.